# Are function declarations function scoped?

Tags: javascript, function, scoping

I have read that in sloppy mode function declarations are function scoped just like var with value of actual functions. But  I want to know why can't I access the inside() function code below:

```js
function outside() {
  var first = 'hello';
  inside();
  if (true) {
    var second = 'second';

    function inside() {
      var third = 'third';
      console.log(third);
    }
    inside();
  }
}
outside();
```

(I have added the snippet above.)
Can someone explain about it?

Comment: Putting a function declaration inside an `if` block is a bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Don't use sloppy mode, problem gone :-)